# Strange behaviour in Excel VSTO 2007 project

Tags: c#, vsto

I have a strange problem. I am working on a vsto project where from a Addin project I am opening a Template project.

Now Once I save the template project for teh initial time and do some changes in it and then I click on the close button [X], Excel does not prompt me

**Do you want to save the changes you made to "some.xlsx"**

But from the next time onwards, it does so(i.e. if I close the template project and open it again and do some changes, the Message appears).

What is wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I forgot to put

```
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
```

That's the fix.

Thanks